# Java - Collection with LinkedHashMap Attributes

Tags: java, collections

Is there a collection class that has the LinkedHashMap quality of a predictable iteration order, but at the same time being indexable? LinkedHashMap implements a get() method, which returns the value object, but an indexof() method is not available. I'd like both.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need a bidirectional map (key -> value, value -> key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have such a thing, a [Linked Tree Map](http://www.softwaremonkey.org/Code/LinkedTree) free and unencumbered on my website.  It sounds close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A SortedMap (ConcurrentSkipListMap, TreeMap) has methods that will return submap views of all keys > (or <) the passed in key. So

```
index(key) == sortedMap.headMap(key).size();
```

Not likely to be terribly efficient.